# How to bypass username/password authentication with mobile/OTP for Keycloak

Tags: java, authentication, keycloak, jboss-wildfly-11

How to bypass username/password authentication with mobile number/OTP (sent via SMS) for Keycloak

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Is this some kind of malicious software or something?

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica the intention is to authenticate with mobile number and the OTP sent to him via SMS instead of username/password credentials. Most of the time users forget the password, hence the above approach. Does it not make sense, I though this is very prevalent for mobile users

Comment: Our intention is to support both approaches, i.e username/password and mobile number/OTP (via SMS) and no 2FA

Comment: That makes more sense, then.

Comment: Not sure why this was closed, if you could state why it was focusing on more than one problem it would be helpful to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement custom authentication flow (see Admin Console -> Authentication -> Flows). Your flow should include two branches: one for login/password, and second for SMS/OTP. For every subflow you should implement dedicated Authenticator SPI with **Conditional** requirement. From client side your applications should supply some data (e.g. additional http param) that will be used by Conditional Authenticators to make a decision about routing through authentication flow.

[Detailed guideline for authentication flow development](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-community/blob/master/design/multi-factor-admin-and-step-up.md)

[Authenticator development docs](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_auth_spi)

P.S. I'm not familiar with latest keycloak version, maybe there are already exists some facilities for your goal.